# Why does 'this' does not bind in ES6 instance methods in React Component without using `=>` or bind?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I understand using `=>` function can help do the static binding of the method with the class.

But, what I don't understand is the opposite, why without using `bind` or `=>` this is not bound in instance methods.

Take this example of a component

```
import React from "react";

export default class ES6Class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderDetails() {
    console.log("With regular function, this refers to: ", this);
    this.showAlert();
  }

  sayHi() {
    alert("oh hi!");
  }

  render() {
    console.log("this in render?", this);
    return <button onClick={this.renderDetails}>Click me!</button>;
  }
}
```

Now, When I run this (https://codesandbox.io/embed/how-does-es6-classes-and-this-work-in-react-h4xm5), I get the following

For

```
console.log("this in render?", this);
```

I get

```
this in render? 
ES6Class {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, _reactInternalFiber: FiberNode…}
```

But when I click on the button, I get

```
With regular function, this refers to:  undefined
```

Now, I have the following questions,

1. In the following code

```
<button onClick={this.renderDetails}>Click me!</button>;
```

What is `this` refer to in `this.renderDetails`? `My 'guess'?` it refers to `ES6Class`,
Why guess? because on button click, it executes the function `renderDetails()`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

2. Why `this` is undefined in

```
renderDetails() {
    console.log("With regular function, this refers to: ", this);
    this.showAlert();
  }
```

When `button` is clicked?

I am super confused. I even read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes, but could not understand this.

Please help me understand and point to official resources if possible. The code is available at

https://codesandbox.io/embed/how-does-es6-classes-and-this-work-in-react-h4xm5

THANK YOU

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks for the answers, I continue to fiddle with it. Next, I tried the following

```
let i = new ES6Class();
i.renderDetails();

let f = i.renderDetails;
f();
```

In this case, what I get is following

```
With regular function, this refers to:  
ES6Class {props: undefined, context: undefined, refs: Object, updater: Object, constructor: Object}

With regular function, this refers to:  undefined
```

Question: why is it `undefined` and not `Global` or `Window`?

Comment: It's basically the same thing as `element.addEventListener('click', this.fn)`. In the block where the listener is added, `this` refers to the instance, but later on, when the listener gets invoked, just the *plain function* was passed - the `this` calling context was lost. Similarly, `callback = this.fn; callback();` results in `this.fn` being called without a calling context

Comment: Why duplicate? I asked `why` and not `how`?

Comment: There are many answers describing *why* it behaves the way it does in the linked canonical.

Comment: In React, in your `<button onClick={this.renderDetails}>Click me!</button>;`, where the listener is attached, `this` refers to the instance, but then when the listener is invoked (which is not directly visible to the coder here), the listener is invoked without a calling context